# Как сделать горизонтальное расположение элементов в RecyclerView и убрать промежутки между элементами?

Tags: java, recyclerview, horizontalscrollview

Код `RecyclerView:`

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/button"
    >
</androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView>
```

Код элемента `RecyclerView:`

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:id="@+id/coin"/>
```

Я выставил горизонтальную ориентацию, но, по какой-то причине, элементы всё равно располагаются горизонтально. Также между ними огромный промежуток, размером с весь экран

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Используйте LinearLayoutManager.
https://androidride.com/horizontal-recyclerview-android-example/

Comment: Спасибо, с горизонтальным расположением разобрался. Но до сих пор не получается сделать так, чтобы элементы шли друг за другом, не получается убрать между ними промежуток, размером с целый экран